# Checking if a UNC Path/Server Folder Exists

Tags: powershell

I am working on a project that utilizes a PowerShell script that creates a new login on a remote SQL Server (SSMS) and then checks to see if a particular folder exists on the server. If the folder does not already exist, the script will create that folder.

The issue I am having is that I cannot verify whether or not the folder exists since the path I am testing is a UNC path of the form "\\server\Files\Log". I have tried many different solutions that I have found through a couple hours of searching online, and all solutions return FALSE even though I am testing a server and folder I know already exist.

I am using PowerGUI to write my script and my system is using PowerShell v5. What I have tried so far:

- `Test-Path $path` (where `$path` has been set to \\server)
- `Test-Path "filesystem::\\Srv"`
- `[System.IO.Directory]::Exists($path)`
- I even tried `[System.IO.Directory]::Exists('G:\')` using all of the
  letters I have network servers mapped to to see if I needed to map to the drives to make it work (all returned FALSE)

What am I missing here? Any thoughts on this topic would be greatly appreciated as I have been grinding on this for a while with no progress being made.

---

EDIT: For anyone who might stumble upon this later, please read the comments, which I found to be super helpful. My main issue was that I was running PowerShell as an administrator which does not have the same permissions as my normal user account. Also note that `Test-Path \\server` alone does not work, a folder must also be referenced.

Comment: Does the server actually have a share `\\server\Files`? If not, try `Test-Path '\\server\G$\Files\Log'`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd be having this issue, I can use Test-Path \\server\folder\file.txt and it returns true. What error are you getting when you use the format I have used? Note: Make sure that you include the extension of the file :)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I am going to ask some of the more experienced devs here to see if there is in fact a share that no one has informed me of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the correct answer:

`Test-Path $path`

or

`Test-Path \\server.domain.tld\ShareName`

If `Test-Path` is returning false, I can think of three things that could be wrong:

- The share does not exist on that server, or at least with the name you expect
- Your user does not have permission to read that share
- You are specifying the short name of the server, and you need the FQDN to resolve it. This is common in multidomain environments.

---

After re-reading your question, it looks like you *might* be running `Test-Path \\server`. You cannot check for the existence of a server this way, you have to specify both the server and the share name at a minimum. If you want to know that a server exists and is online, use `Test-Connection` (assuming you are able to `ping` this server in the first place). Here is an example of using `Test-Connection`:

```
$serverName = 'server.domain.tld'
$sharePath = 'ShareName' # you can append more paths here
if( Test-Connection $serverName 2> $null ){
  Test-Path "\\${serverName}\${sharePath}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am thinking that the issue is related to your second point. If I just use powershell by itself (not the script editor) I get FALSE when I run as administrator and TRUE when I run powershell as normal. I am new to my position and was told by coworkers to always run PS as Admin, but that is obviously not a great thing to do, particularly in this case apparently. I am going to look more into this aspect.

Comment: It depends on your environment as there are non-default settings that can change this, but typically as long as your shell is just an elevated shell belonging to your user you should still have the same network permissions. If you are running Powershell as a local admin that isn't your user, you won't have the permissions you expect. Also, by default mapped drives will not show up in an elevated session, although you can use `New-PSDrive` to restore them at runtime.

Comment: One last blurb, if your environment does not allow you to elevate your own shell to admin, but you must run the shell as the local administrator, look at creating a `PSCredential` with the `Get-Credential` cmdlet. In that scenario, simply use your normal username and password to create a `PSCredential`, which can be passed into most other cmdlets that might require authentication, `Test-Path` included.

Comment: I really appreciate the comments you made as I expect those might be useful for myself and for others in the future. I also did not realize that you cannot just use `Test-Path \\server` which is probably also an issue. I am glad you answered this very beginner question because I have not yet found any articles that fully discuss these finer details. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used to have an issue where the file existed, but test-path is returning false. I put test-path in a loop that checks a maximum of 10 x, with a one sec pause in between. The script works fine now. If on the first attempt it does not find the file on the second or third it does. Not sure why it returns false on the first attempt.